# Can I locally retrieve the cwd of a remote shell on the other side of a ssh connection?

Tags: bash, ssh, proc

Lets say I run the following commands:

```
user1@172.50.50.50:~$ ssh user2@172.51.51.51:/Documents
user2@172.51.51.51:~/Documents$ cd ~/Desktop/
user2@172.51.51.51:~/Desktop$ pwd
/home/user2/Desktop
```

Is there a way for me to get the path /home/user2/Desktop from the pid of the ssh process from another process on 172.50.50.50?

I thought maybe it would be somewhere in `/proc/<SSH PID>/` but I can't figure it out.

Comment: do you have permission to read other's `proc` directory?

Comment: That information doesn't exist on the client side at all; as Toby's answer says, the server never sends it over-the-wire. That said, why do you think you need it? There are much better ways to do anything that might depend on at information (for instance, if you're trying to drive a long-running interactive session from the remote, *stop doing that* and instead open a new channel over the same transport for each individual command you want, changing the directory as appropriate for that command when you start it).

Comment: ("channel" and "transport" is SSH protocol terminology, but you can access the same functionality with OpenSSH's ControlMaster and ControlSocket configuration knobs).

Comment: Another pertinent thing is that when you `cd ~/Desktop`, you aren't even changing the working directory of the ssh process on the server at all; you're only changing the working directory of a shell that ssh process started. The SSH server doesn't know what the `cd` command means to a shell, and it's not its business to know -- it's just sending characters to the shell and reading output back.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I use i3 as my window manager. I have a bash script that I use so that when I hit $mod+Enter it finds the cwd of shell in the currently focused window and then opens a new terminal in the same dir. I would like the same thing to happen when I am sshed into another box. It seems like I'm going to need to be a bit more creative if I want that to work. Thanks

Comment: Graeme, you could improve the question a lot with that information, especially if you show the script and how it's plugged in to the window manager.  At present, how does it determine "the shell" of the focused window, and what does it do if there's no shell, or many shells?

Comment: @Graeme, I'd tackle that by setting the window title (requiring a TERM that supports this, of course) to contain both host and directory information, and parsing and leveraging that from your script. Of course, you'll need to code defensively to prevent a remote server from convincing your code to run things it shouldn't by setting a malicious window title.

Comment: @Graeme, ...however, that suggestion is well outside the scope of the question as you asked it, since it doesn't actually relate very closely to the thing you intend to accomplish. Which is to say, you've asked a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

The SSH client has no knowledge of the server's working directory.  It's not transmitted anywhere in the SSH protocol.  In fact, there's no need for the SSH server to know the working directory of the process (group) that it's transferring characters to and from.

The only way to get what you want is to independently access the server host, locate the corresponding sshd process and the particular child process, then interrogate that child.

It's not trivial to even know which child process is relevant - you may have three or four shells in foreground, background or stopped, and perhaps some editors and other application programs, all with different working directories.  Which one of those is required?

Comment: Can you think of any way to associate a process on the server with a process on the client?

Answer (score 0):

If you have sufficient permission on the server and know the ssh pid, you can do:

```
ls -l /proc/<SSH PID>/cwd
```

the `/proc/<pid>/cwd` is a symlink, link to the process `cwd`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time putting my problem into words. From my example - I want to get the path from another process on 172.50.50.50. On 172.50.50.50, `/proc/<SSH PID>/cwd` gives me the dir that I was in when I called ssh.